# Jquery $(this).after('<div class="loading"></div>'); problem?

Tags: jquery

I am using an onblur event on a form and currently have this as code for the loading to work...

```
$('#username').after('<div class="loading"></div>');
```

Only this will work for the id of username, I thought changing it to (this) like

```
$(this).after('<div class="loading"></div>');
```

Would in turn make the div appear after the input field of any fields where the script is used, why is this not happening??

**Update**

Just tried the following which also does not work... Where I assigned the class loading to the input field.

```
$('.loading').(this).after('<div class="loading"></div>');
```

Comment: who knows? You haven't provided enough code.

Comment: It should appear after every field that fires the event as `$(this)` will refer to the element that fires the `onblur`.

Comment: Why not use jQuery's event.target rather than `this`? Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ to share an example.

Comment: @Matt That is all the code, I call it in the form using onblur, and that is the only thing I want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it must be appending but as the div is empty its not showing, see in the firebug it should be there. or for testing purpose you can try

```
$("#username").blur(function(){

$(this).after('<div class="loading">test</div>');

});
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QxMWh/

and this one http://jsfiddle.net/QxMWh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('.loading', this).after('<div class="loading"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand correctly,
you have a form, with a few fields having a certain script (validation or autocomplete or anything like that..)

now you want a loading div inserted after the field, when it is blurred.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input class="toBeProcessed" type="text" id="Name"></input>  <!-- this field will be selected thanks to the class 'toBeProcessed' -->
  <input type="text" id="age"></input>  <!-- this field won't be processed -->
</form>
```

javascript (with jquery):

```
$('#myForm input.toBeProcessed').blur(function(){
  var inputEl = $(this);
  inputEl.after('<div class="loading"></div>');

  doMyOtherScript(inputEl);
});
```

in this same blur event you should be triggering the script that does what you want, and after that the script should be removing the loading div again ...